# JavaFX webview, get document height

Tags: java, javascript, html, javafx

How can I get the document height for a webview control in JavaFx?

Comment: Java and Javascript are quite different. Also, please expand your question, perhaps with what you have tried.

Comment: I have an webview control and I want to set it's height relative at the document height.

Comment: Please update your question by clicking edit. Your comment merely rearranges the words in your original question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the height of a document displayed in a WebView using the following call:

```
webView.getEngine().executeScript(
    "window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null).getPropertyValue('height')"
);
```

---

A complete app to demonstrate the call usage:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class WebViewHeight extends Application {
  @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final WebView webView = new WebView();
    final WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
    engine.load("http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/animation.htm");
    engine.documentProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Document>() {
      @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Document> prop, Document oldDoc, Document newDoc) {
        String heightText = webView.getEngine().executeScript(
          "window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null).getPropertyValue('height')"
        ).toString();
        double height = Double.valueOf(heightText.replace("px", ""));    

        System.out.println(height);
      }
    });
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(webView));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

---

Source of the above answer: [Oracle JavaFX forums WebView configuration thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=10049488).

---

Related issue tracker request for a Java based API for a related feature:

[RT-25005 Automatic preferred sizing of WebView](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-25005).

Comment: It works, however the result is not true. I measured via pixel line, the height was about 480px and the code returned 414px.

Comment: Thanks for your anser. This is a bit late reply. Your example is running. However I have a webview, which is embedded in an `TableCell`. Here the result is always 0 px (Close to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334983/java-fx-tableview-display-simple-html/22335276#22335276) any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Kindly see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856471/workaround-for-rt-25005-automatic-preferred-sizing-of-webview   for more specific question including running example.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
Double.parseDouble(webView.getEngine().executeScript("document.height").toString())
```