# Correct sizing of Webview embedded in Tabelcell

Tags: javafx, webview

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334983/java-fx-tableview-display-simple-html/22335276#22335276) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838965/size-javafx-webview-to-the-minimum-size-needed-by-the-document-body) there is no easy way to determine the required height of a webview, until "RT-25005 Automatic preferred sizing of WebView" is implemented.

Are there any workarounds to this issue? I couldn't find a solution in SO or elsewhere. However since i think this is no uncommon problem, there needs to be a workaround. Any idea?

For `Webviews`embeded in a `stage` I found the following solution (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736012/javafx-webview-get-document-height/15753155#comment72820480_15753155)):

```
webView.getEngine().executeScript(
    "window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null).getPropertyValue('height')"
);
```

or

```
Double.parseDouble(webView.getEngine().executeScript("document.height").toString())
```

However this doesn't seem to work for Webviews embedded in a treecell, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334983/java-fx-tableview-display-simple-html/22335276#22335276). In this case I always get too big numbers as a result.

Minimal running example (including recommendation of `jewelsea`):

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class TableViewSampleHTML extends Application {

    private final ObservableList<MyData> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new MyData(1L), new MyData(3L), new MyData(2L), new MyData(4L), new MyData(1L));

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        final Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());

        TableView<MyData> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setPrefHeight(700);

        final TableColumn<MyData, Long> nameCol = new TableColumn("So So");
        nameCol.setMinWidth(200);
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("i"));

        // Allow to display Textflow in Column
        nameCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<MyData, Long>, TableCell<MyData, Long>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<MyData, Long> call(TableColumn<MyData, Long> column) {
                return new TableCell<MyData, Long>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Long item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);

                        if (item == null || empty) {

                            setText(null);
                            setGraphic(null);
                            setStyle("");

                        } else {

                            WebView webview = new WebView();
                            webview.setPrefWidth(700.0);
                            WebEngine engine = webview.getEngine();

                            String textHTML = new String(new char[item.intValue()]).replace("\0", " <b> bold </b> normal, ");
                         //   textHTML = "<body>" 
                           //         + textHTML + "</body>";
                            engine.loadContent(textHTML);


                           setGraphic(webview);



                            engine.documentProperty().addListener((obj, prev, newv) -> {

                                    String heightText = engine.executeScript(
                                         "window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null).getPropertyValue('height')"
                                    ).toString();

                                    System.out.println("heighttext: " + heightText);
                                    webview.setPrefHeight(Double.parseDouble(heightText.replace("px", "")));
                                    this.setPrefHeight(Double.parseDouble(heightText.replace("px", "")));
                                    setGraphic(webview);

                            });





                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(nameCol);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(table);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class MyData {

        private Long i;

        public MyData(Long i) {
            this.i = i;
        }

        public Long getI() {
            return i;
        }
    }

}
```

Now the outout is

```
heighttext: 581px
heighttext: 581px
```

However these values seem to be too big. See screeenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some progress has been made and cell heights are now calculated more realisticly. Kindly see the relevant the adapted code below.

Relevant changens:

- Seems like it is mandatory to call `webview.setPrefHeight(-1);` before executing the jevascript.
- Javascript has been modified. No big change seen, but maybe the result is more general

Open points:

- For some reason i still have to add `+ 15.0` to the calculated height. This is a hack. Seems like some additional lenght has to be considered somewhere.
- Functionality on recalculation after resize of column has is not optimal. Using `table.refresh()` causes significant delay in rendering.

  ```
  public class TableViewSampleHTML extends Application {

  private final ObservableList<MyData> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new MyData(1L), new MyData(14L), new MyData(2L), new MyData(3L), new MyData(15L));

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(final Stage stage) {
      final Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 400, 800);

      TableView<MyData> table = new TableView<>();

      table.setPrefWidth(400);
      table.setPrefHeight(800);

      final TableColumn<MyData, Long> nameCol = new TableColumn("So So");
      final TableColumn<MyData, Long> col2 = new TableColumn("la la");
      nameCol.setPrefWidth(200);
      col2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("i"));
      nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("i"));
      nameCol.widthProperty().addListener((ob,oldV,newV) -> {table.refresh();} );

      // Allow to display Textflow in Column
      nameCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<MyData, Long>, TableCell<MyData, Long>>() {

          @Override
          public TableCell<MyData, Long> call(TableColumn<MyData, Long> column) {

              return new TableCell<MyData, Long>() {

                  @Override
                  protected void updateItem(Long item, boolean empty) {
                      super.updateItem(item, empty);

                      if (item == null || empty) {

                          setText(null);
                          setGraphic(null);
                          setStyle("");

                      } else {
                          WebView webview = new WebView();
                          WebEngine engine = webview.getEngine();

                          webview.setPrefHeight(-1);   // <- Absolute must at this position (before calling the Javascript)
                          setGraphic(webview);

                          String textHTML = new String(new char[item.intValue()]).replace("\0", " <b> bold </b> normal, ");
                          textHTML = "<body>" 
                                  + textHTML + "</body>";
                          engine.loadContent(textHTML);


                          engine.documentProperty().addListener((obj, prev, newv) -> {

                          String heightText = engine.executeScript(   // <- Some modification, which gives moreless the same result than the original
                                  "var body = document.body,"
                                  + "html = document.documentElement;"
                                  + "Math.max( body.scrollHeight , body.offsetHeight, "
                                  + "html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight , html.offsetHeight );"
                          ).toString();

                          System.out.println("heighttext: " + heightText);
                          Double height = Double.parseDouble(heightText.replace("px", "")) + 15.0;  // <- Why are this 15.0 required??
                          webview.setPrefHeight(height);
                          this.setPrefHeight(height);
                          });
                      }

                  }
              };
          }
      });

      table.setItems(data);
      table.getColumns().addAll(nameCol);
      table.getColumns().addAll(col2);

      ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(table);

      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
  }

  public static class MyData {

      private Long i;

      public MyData(Long i) {
          this.i = i;
      }

      public Long getI() {
          return i;
      }
  }
  }
  ```

Output now looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this code.

HTML body tag by default has topmargin and leftmargins so You need to set topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 to get rid of margins.(<body topmargin=0 leftmargin=0>) So now to have no vertical scrollbar you need to add extra 10 here: Double height = Double.parseDouble(heightText.replace("px", "")) + 10.0;

Comment: I found the calculated height to have a drift factor of `1.0054` on my Mac.  Will test on other machines, but wanted to share but simply applying this multiplier makes the sizing perfect.

Answer (score 1):

From the example you linked ([JavaFX webview, get document height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736012/javafx-webview-get-document-height/15753155#comment72820480_15753155)) the height of the document is computed in a `ChangeListener` on the document:

```
engine.documentProperty().addListener((prop, oldDoc, newDoc) -> {
    String heightText = engine.executeScript(
            "window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null).getPropertyValue('height')"
    ).toString();

    System.out.println("heighttext: " + heightText);
});
```

Output:

```
heighttext: 36px
heighttext: 581px
heighttext: 581px
```

In the code in your question you are not executing the height check based upon a ChangeListener.  So you are querying the height of the WebView document before the document has been loaded (which is why it is returning zero for your code).

Comment: Thank you jewelsea. This makes it a bit clearer to me. Now the numbers are not zero anymore. However they now seem to be too high. Kindly review my edit.

Comment: Sorry BerndGit, I don't know a way to get a more accurate WebView document size count.

Comment: No Problem. Thanks for Feedback. I think i'll issue a bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Basedon BerndGirt's answer.

```
public class WebviewCellFactory<S,T> implements Callback<TableColumn<S,T>, TableCell<S,T>> {
    @Override
    public TableCell<S, T> call(TableColumn<S, T> column) {
        return new TableCell<S, T>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                    setStyle("");
                } else {
                    WebView webview = new WebView();
                    WebEngine engine = webview.getEngine();
                    webview.setPrefHeight(-1);   // <- Absolute must at this position (before calling the Javascript)
                    webview.setBlendMode(BlendMode.DARKEN);

                    setGraphic(webview);
                    engine.loadContent("<body topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 style=\"background-color: transparent;\">"+item+"</body>");
                    engine.documentProperty().addListener((obj, prev, newv) -> {
                        String heightText = engine.executeScript(   // <- Some modification, which gives moreless the same result than the original
                                "var body = document.body,"
                                        + "html = document.documentElement;"
                                        + "Math.max( body.scrollHeight , body.offsetHeight, "
                                        + "html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight , html.offsetHeight );"
                        ).toString();
                        Double height = Double.parseDouble(heightText.replace("px", "")) + 10 ;  // <- Why are this 15.0 required??
                        webview.setPrefHeight(height);
                        this.setPrefHeight(height);
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

then you just need to set

```
tableColumn.setCellFactory(new WebviewCellFactory());
```

if there are any mistakes please tell me.