# fit the content to WebView in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a problem in getting the size of the content of a web view..here is my code

```
 String heightText = (String) engine.executeScript("window.getComputedStyle(document.body,null).getPropertyValue('height')");
    double height = Double.valueOf(heightText.replace("px", ""));
    String widthText = web1.getEngine().executeScript(
            "window.getComputedStyle(document.body,null).getPropertyValue('width')"
    ).toString();
    double width = Double.valueOf(widthText.replace("px", ""));
    web1.setPrefHeight(height);
    web1.setPrefWidth(width);
    System.out.println(height + "  " + width);


}
```

but it refers 0 at first time and in the other times it has wrong result.

actually I had to edit my question. the above code shows the size of the previous content.. why is it like this?
please help. thank you

Comment: Please specify the proper version of Java FX that you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this code is called after `Stage.show()` or code displaying corresponding window. All height and width getters returns zero before UI initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you wait until the document has loaded before retrieving document properties.  Use a change listener on the state property of a load worker as outlined in the [WebEngine javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html).

Disclaimer: I haven't tried to do this for a long time, so the technique may or may not work with current and later JavaFX versions.

---

If you want to [generate a layout pass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#applyCss--) for the scene graph, use the applyCss/layout functions, otherwise modifying the prefWidth of something, then getting the set width will not probably not match-up.

---

See also:

- [JavaFX webview, get document height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736012/javafx-webview-get-document-height)
- [JDK-8091167
  Automatic preferred sizing of WebView](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091167)